# Instance variable is nil when accessed from block

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks, null, eventkit

I'm using the EventKit API to fetch a user's Reminders. The fetch API is done asynchrounously and when the fetch is finished there is a completion block you can use. However after I have fetched the user's Reminders I assign it to the self.eventKitReminderEvents instance variable (I have debugged and seen that it's not nil). Then right after I'm calling a block, but from inside this block self.eventKitReminderEvents is **nil**. I don't really understand why that is happening. Maybe someone can take a look at my code and give me a clue.

I'm using the API like this:

```
- (void)futureReminders {

    dispatch_semaphore_t sema = dispatch_semaphore_create(0);

    [self fetchReminderEventsInBackgroundFromDate:[NSDate date] withCompletionBlock:^{

        // When I enter here self.eventKitReminderEvents is nil
        // Which is weird because it should be set already if you look in
        // fetchReminderEventsInBackgroundFromDate below...

        [self processEventKitRemindersWithCompletion:^(NSArray *reminderEvents) {

            // Save a copy in memory
            self.futureReminderEvents = reminderEvents;

            // Send a signal that indicates that this asynchronous task is completed ...
            dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema);
         }];
    }];

    // Wait for dispatch signal
    dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);

}

- (void)fetchReminderEventsInBackgroundFromDate:(NSDate *)startDate withCompletionBlock:(void(^)(void))block {

    DLogName()

    //NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDate *endDate = [NSDate distantFuture]; // This will get me events 4 years from now

    // Create the predicate
    NSPredicate *predicate = [self.eventStore predicateForIncompleteRemindersWithDueDateStarting:startDate ending:endDate calendars:nil];

    [self.eventStore fetchRemindersMatchingPredicate:predicate completion:^(NSArray *reminders) {

        self.eventKitReminderEvents = reminders;
        block();
    }];
}
```

Comment: Show the code how you created instance variable or it is just an ivar?

Comment: @AKV It's just a NSArray property - `@property (nonatomic, strong)                                   NSArray *eventKitReminderEvents;`

Comment: Am not sure, atleast give a try by putting it in { and }.

Comment: old style ivars. `@implementation { NSString *string; } @end` This way.

Comment: Are you sure that self.eventKitReminderEvents is set correctly before calling block(); ? Have you tried to NSLog it?

Comment: @LombaX yes, check the code that I have provided...

Comment: I tried your code (removing processEventKitRemindersWithCompletion because I don't know the implementation :-) , and in my case self.eventKitReminderEvents is set correctly. At this point I would search the problem outside this code...try to override the setter for eventKitReminderEvents and look if something is setting it to nil before entering the block (assuming that it's using the setter and not the instance variable directly...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers/comments I received. I just noticed that I was actually setting another instance variable with a similair name so that's why it was nil.

Note to self: be very careful when copying and pasting code :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a selfInBlock sow to make sure you don't loose the reference to self inside the block like this

```
__block YourSelfClassName *selfInBlock = self;
```

and use selfInBlock instead of self inside the block.

Comment: what? this doesn't make sense. `__block` is only useful when the variable is assigned to somewhere, or in MRC to prevent the block from retaining it. Neither of those things are relevant here

Comment: i misunderstood the question.